# error after reload div using jquery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with id content
here is my script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#avt").fileinput();
        $('#updateuser').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if($('#pwd').val() == $('#repwd').val()){
                var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'user/edit',
                    data: formData,
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#content").load(location.href + " #content");
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('#errordisplay').html('   <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> <h4><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i> Alert!</h4> Nhập lại password không đúng!Xin nhập lại!</div>');
            }


        });

    });
</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRYok.png)

at the first click update,data updated but I look like the javascript not working anymore and css error.

here is image when page normal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aocb0.png)

here is content div

```
<div class="body-content outer-top-xs" id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="box wow fadeInUp outer-bottom-xs animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
        <h3 class="section-title">Thông Tin Người Dùng</h3>
        <div class="box-body outer-top-xs">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <img src="<?= upload_url() ?>/avt/<?= $info['avatar'] ?>" class="img-responsive img-circle" ></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <hr>
                <span class="text-bold">Họ và Tên : </span><span class="text-muted"><?= $info['fullname'] ?> ( <?= $info['username'] ?>)</span>
                <hr>
                <span class="text-bold">Ngày Đăng Kí : </span><span class="text-muted"><?= $info['date_register'] ?></span>
                <hr>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.sidebar-widget-body -->
    </div></div>


<div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="box wow fadeInUp outer-bottom-xs animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
        <h3 class="section-title">Cập Nhật Thông Tin</h3>
        <div class="box-body outer-top-xs">
            <form class="form-horizontal" id="updateuser">
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="avt" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Avatar</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input name="img" class="file" type="file" >
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?= $info['username'] ?>">
                            <input id="uid" name="uid" type="hidden" readonly="readonly" value="<?= $info['userid'] ?>">
                        </div>
                        <label for="fullname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Họ Tên </label>

                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input class="form-control" id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="Fullname" type="text" value="<?= $info['fullname'] ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="pwd" class="col-sm-2 control-label">New Pwd</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input class="form-control" id="pwd" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" type="password" >
                        </div>
                        <label for="repwd" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Reinput</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input class="form-control" id="repwd" name="repwd" placeholder=" Retype Password" type="password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email *</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input class="form-control" required id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" value="<?= $info['email'] ?>">
                        </div>
                        <label for="addr" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Địa Chỉ</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input class="form-control" id="addr" name="addr" placeholder="Địa Chỉ" type="text" value="<?= $info['address'] ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="gender" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Giới Tính</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="0" <?php if($info['gender'] ==0) echo 'checked' ?> >Nam</label>
                            <label class="col-sm-3 radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="1" <?php if($info['gender'] ==1) echo 'checked' ?>>Nữ</label>
                            <label class="col-sm-3 radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="2" <?php if($info['gender'] ==2) echo 'checked' ?>>Khác</label>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label">SĐT</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Số Điện Thoại" type="text" value="<?= $info['phone'] ?>">
                        </div>
                        <label for="group" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Group</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <select class="form-control" id="group" name="group">
                                <?php foreach($listgroup as $item): ?>
                                    <option value="<?= $item['groupid'] ?>" <?php if($info['groupid'] ==$item['groupid']) echo 'selected' ?>><?= $item['name'] ?></option>
                                <?php endforeach ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
                <div class="box-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn bg-tit pull-right">Update</button>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-footer -->
        </form>

        </div>
        <!-- /.sidebar-widget-body -->
    </div></div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</div>
```

Comment: Show us your `#content` HTML Code..

Comment: I've updated!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#content").load(location.href + " #content");
```

should be

```
$("#content").load(location.href + " #content > *");
```